# Project explorer like view using JavaFX e4 application

Tags: java, javafx, rcp, e4

Is it possible to add the Project Explorer to an Eclipse JavaFX e4 application? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

No. Project Explorer is SWT code and also uses 3.x compatiblity mode.

Comment: Thank you Greg. What would you recommend If I want to develop a Eclipse like application using advantages of JavaFX?

Comment: I don't use JavaFX so I don't know. Note that a pure e4 RCP doesn't have any of the file APIs etc. used by a workspace style application either.